# Show attachments in operation dashboard

Tags: arcgis-online, operations-dashboard

I have set up an operation dashboard to help keep track of field work. The field staff are using the field maps app to collect information and photos of point features. Is there anyway to get the photos saved as attachments to show up in one of the widgets? I can access them through pop ups in the map but viewing them larger opens a new tab and I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Are the photos attachments to the points features, or just URLs?

Comment: They are attachments, I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ["Details"](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/dashboards/get-started/details.htm) element provides this functionality.